# Get values and formulas of a workbook by JavaScript API for Excel 2013?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I often need to collect the values and formulas of the usedRange of all the worksheets. I am wondering how to do this by JavaScript API for Excel **2013**.

It seems that the only way to get/read data is via [binding](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.bindings). There are for example `MatrixBindings` and `TableBindings`. But I don't see how to bind to a fixed area (let's say `A1:Z1000` of `Sheet1`).

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get the values in a named range in Excel 2013:

```js
var myBindings = Office.context.document.bindings;
myBindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Sheet1!A1:Z1000", "matrix", {}, function (asyncResult) {
    asyncResult.value.getDataAsync(function (asyncResult2) {
        console.log(asyncResult2.value);
    });
});
```

There isn't any way to get the formulas in 2013.

I should note the smaller API set available for Excel 2013 isn't really designed for getting the entire contents of sheets, but the above code will still work for this narrow case.

-Michael Saunders (Program Manager for add-ins in Office)

Comment: And is there a way to get the list of all the worksheets? Moreover, it is not possible to get `usedRange`, right?

Comment: You can't get a list of all worksheets, but you can reference the current worksheet by just saying "A1:Z1000". And yes, `usedRange` is not available